# SQL statement and DAX expressions

Tags: sql, powerbi, data-visualization, dax, visualization

please I want to convert this sql statement to DAX in power BI to create a new table then create a visual from the resulting table. Does anyone have an idea on how to go about it?

```
SELECT a.name account_name, r.name region_name
FROM sales_reps s
JOIN accounts a ON s.id = a.sales_rep_id
JOIN region r ON s.region_id = r.id
GROUP BY account_name, region_name;
```

The accounts table has 351 rows and 7 columns, while the region has two columns and four rows.

[The statement joins the regions table to the accounts table and gives this result, it returns a total of 351 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUGYo.png)

[this is the ERD of the tables I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiikb.png)

Here's the link to my dataset.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GsP-gk4ISJanimTTzZKM5TM0SAOS5ggd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use Power Query within Power BI to make the joins? You can join two different tables using the "Merge Queries" option in Power Query. You can also do groupings within Power BI. This would be far easier than trying to do the same in DAX.

Comment: ok, I'll try that out

Comment: hello @codyho I tried using the merge query option but it didn't work. What else can i do to perform this joins other than my suggestion?